# After exception specifications being part of type system, we still couldn't deduce noexcept(B) in template functions?

Tags: c++, clang, c++17

I tried following code in [wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/p0JiFKyo7PKH0Gpw) :

```
template<bool B>
void Func(void(*)() noexcept(B)) {}

int main()
{
    Func(+[]() noexcept {});
}
```

Compile error:

```
prog.cc:7:5: error: no matching function for call to 'Func'
    Func(+[]() noexcept {});
    ^~~~
prog.cc:3:6: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'B'
void Func(void(*)() noexcept(B)) {}
1 error generated.
     ^
```

Why can't B be deduced?

Comment: Why would you expect that to work?

Comment: @NicolBolas Well, because it would be nice, and the C++ standard tends to provide nice things.

Comment: @Yakk A good question on this subject might be written, but this is not it. A lambda is not a function, so this would never work.

Comment: @t.c. it was 2 characters off.  Fixed.  (I'll risk the slim chance that the error message would change; if that is the case, revert my edit and we can close as a typo...)

Comment: This was noticed here: http://sourcerytools.com/pipermail/cxx-abi-dev/2016-October/002983.html and I hope Richard will convince the committee to enable deduction of `noexcept(B)` for C++17.